# Any benefits of using Looper for Producer-Consumer pattern?

Tags: android, producer-consumer, android-looper

In my app there are few threads with `while-on-volatile-boolean` loops and `BlockingQueue`s for quite simple objects-messages they process (pipelined architecture).

Recently I've encountered `android.os.Looper` class with it's friends, that seems to do the same job, but they are placed in API, so are there any benefits(especially performance) of using them instead of handwritten loops with explicit queues? or is it just some kind of "API sugar"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Looper` is just a regular Java Thread that waits until messages are posted to it. `Looper` is used with the `Handler` class and the `Message` class. Handlers post Messages on the Looper thread. The Looper thread keeps a thread alive and loops through Messages posted by Handler.

Performance wise, there would be no advantage as far as I'm aware. It's simply keeping threads alive and posting messages to those threads.  From an API point-of-view, it may be easier to use a Handler. You can create multiple Handlers that all share the same Looper. Have them post to the Looper in a thread-safe manner. There are also handy timing messages like `Handler#postDelayed`. So it would just be less code to worry about.

The disadvantage is they are Android only APIs, so you are restricted to that environment.

Comment: ANother big difference-  you can post a generic Runnable to a Looper via Handler.  You generally don't do that when you write your own message handler (you could, you generally code to specific messages though).  That an be a positive or a negative.

Comment: @GabeSechan well, that's possible with `ExecutorService`s too.

Comment: Thanks for noticing about timing messages, I've missed that `Handler` class is that complex. So it's actually has a use when more intelligent message queuing needed.